# Phonegap facebook login plugin can not import java.io.IOException

Tags: java, android, facebook, cordova

everybody.

I tried Phonegap Facebook Login plugin at https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin. But I got an error like the picture bellow.

But the interesting is I run the example at https://github.com/jimzim/phonegap-facebook-android-sample on the same workspace, it work well.

Could anyone tell me what wrong here and how to fix it?

[image: Can not import IOException]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this issue. Just go to Project Properties >> Java Build Path >> Add JARS >> Add Cordova-3.0.0.jar and it work well.

But I'm still confuse on the required cordova version of Apache Cordova Facebook Plugin. In the README file, it said that "Supported on PhoneGap (Cordova) v2.1.0 and above.", but my cordova version is 2.8, but it not work... Could anyone tell me how to use this plugin with cordova 2.8. I don't want to upgrade to version 3.0.

Thankyou.

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin